# Padding a multidimensional array with array_pad

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is output of my array how can I use `array_pad()` to make all of equal lengths or padd with 0.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 'xy'
                [1] => 'yz'
                [2] => 'ab'
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 'xy'
                [1] => 'xy'
                [2] => 'yz'
                [3] => 'yz'
            )
          [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 'xy'
                [1] => 'xy'
                [3] => 'xy'
            )

    )
```

I already calculated the size of the biggest array is in var `$size`. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_map, to call array_pad on the inner array.

```
array_map(function($v) use($size){
                  return array_pad($v, $size, 0);
          }, $array);
```

[Manual reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Ok `$v` is my array and `$size` is the max size but still it's not working

Comment: no $array is your array, and array_map() output is the result.

Comment: you can refer to array_map() for the usage.

Comment: `Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array` this warning showing]

Comment: print_r your array here, your data is not an array.

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )

)`
this is print_r looks like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144990/discussion-between-gautam-jha-and-kris-roofe).